# issue in importing csv logstash 2.3.4 windows

Tags: csv, logstash

1. **Logstash.conf**

   ```
   input {    
       file {
           path => "C:\xampp\htdocs\logstash\sample.csv"
           sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
       }
   }
   filter {
       csv {
           columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]      
           separator => "," 
       }
   }
   output {
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => "localhost:9200"
           index => "stocks"       
           document_type => "stock"
       }
   }
   ```

   **Error stuck at:**

   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] (c) 2015 Microsoft
   Corporation. All rights reserved.

   `C:\Users\user1>cd C:\xampp\htdocs\logstash`

   `C:\xampp\htdocs\logstash>logstash -f logstash.conf -v io/console not
   supported; tty will not be manipulated starting agent`

   ```
   {:level=>:info} starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :level=>:info}
   Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4 Registering file input
   {:path=>["C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\logstash\\sample.csv"], :level=>:info}

   Using mapping template from {:path=>nil, :level=>:info} Attempting
   to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*",
   "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"},
   "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true,
   "omit_norms"=>true},
   "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"match"=>"message",
   "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string",
   "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true,
   "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"}}}},
   {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string",
   "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed",
   "omit_norms"=>true, "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"},
   "fields"=>{"raw"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed",
   "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}],
   "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"},
   "@version"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed"},
   "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"},
   "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"float"},
   "longitude"=>{"type"=>"float"}}}}}}}, :level=>:info} New

   Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch",
   :hosts=>["localhost:9200"], :level=>:info} Starting pipeline
   {:id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>4, :batch_size=>125,
   :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>500, :level=>:info} Pipeline main started
   ```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It seems that your logstash pipeline starts normally.

Comment: I am not receiving any response after "Pipeline main started", can u pls let me know where the error is?

Comment: Still it seems evertyhing is ok. You need to specify what __exactly__ isn't working? Can't you stash events? Can't you access the elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: clusters are not created.

Comment: Is your elasticsearch actually running?

Comment: yes running fine.

Answer (score 1):

could be Windows style paths not supported; therefore, try change this

```
path => "C:\xampp\htdocs\logstash\sample.csv"
```

to

```
path => "C:/xampp/htdocs/logstash/sample.csv"
```

works on my Logstash.